# Flask docker health check

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I am trying to get the health status of a Flask Docker container. This container is not exposing port 5000 it talks to wsgi server and then I use Nginx as a socket proxy to Flask. The Flask container is running Flask and uwsgi.  I was able to get health check working on Nginx, but not on Flask container.  Everytime I check the healthStatus the Flask continer shows as unhealthy.  Although it is showing up as unhealthy the site and API is fully functional.  This is in a Dev enviroment at the moment.  I have tried just localhost and localhost:5000 on the portcheck and none seem to work for me, both return unhealthy. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]

module = wsgi:app
master = true
processes = 5
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true

buffer-size = 32768

socket= api.sock
chmod-socket = 664
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
```

wsgi.py

```
from flask_project import create_app

app = create_app()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

init.py

```
from flask import Flask


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    ## internal configs here
    
    return app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.7-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential python-dev libssl-dev openssl procps curl
COPY ./ .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "uwsgi.ini"
```

Docker-compose:

```
---
version: "3.7"
services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: ./docker
    container_name: flask
    environment:
      - CONTAINER=flask
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app
    restart: on-failure
    stdin_open: true
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost:5000/ || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on:
      - flask
    volumes:
      - ./nginx_config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./app/:/app
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost/ || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
```

Comment: Can you share the error output you see in the pod description? why is it failing? also, did you define somewhere a route on "/"? what url are you using for the nginx check you say that passes? anyway, pretty sure you need to define a route on "/" in order for this to work

Comment: I am not seeing any errors on the Flask logs, just the Nginx health check which is is being proxyed to Flask and it is going to the same / route.  The "/" route is working and up and it passed on the Nginx side, but the same route does not on Flask.

Comment: where did you define a route for `/`? you did not include it in your code examples. if you did not define it, that is the problem. you should have a function with this decorator `@app.route("/")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `healthcheck` for your `flask` service, try using `test: curl --fail http://nginx/ || exit 1`.

I believe it has to do with how Docker handles network namespaces. In the `flask` container, `localhost` points specifically to the network address of the `flask` container, not the network address where the container is being run. Nothing in the `flask` container is listening on port `5000` because, as you say, you are not exposing it. It is the `nginx` container that is listening for traffic (and using port forwarding from `443` and `80` on the host's address to `443` and `80` on its own address), so you have to point your `curl` command at the address of the `nginx` container. It was working for the `nginx` container because in that container's context, `localhost` points at itself.

As an aside, I came across this trying to figure out whether it's best practice put the health check on the `flask` container, the `nginx` container, or both.